# Django site on Ubuntu 18.04 with Apache2 not working after installing SSL

Tags: django, ssl, apache2, mod-wsgi, certbot

I'm trying to deploy my Djang(1.10) application on Ubuntu 18.04 with Apache2 using mode_wsgi, the site was working perfectly well before setting up the SSL, but when I install the SSL certificate from Let'sEncrypt using `certbot` the is not loading anymore.

Here's my configurations:

**Project folder path:**

```
/home/abdul
```

**`Http` configuration:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.

    ServerName www.orderfetchers.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

    Alias /static /home/abdul/Fetchors/static
      <Directory /home/abdul/Fetchors/static>
        Require all granted
      </Directory>

      Alias /media /home/abdul/Fetchors/media
      <Directory /home/abdul/Fetchors/media>
        Require all granted
      </Directory>

      <Directory /home/abdul/Fetchors/Fetchors>
        <Files wsgi.py>
          Require all granted
        </Files>
      </Directory>
    #WSGIScriptAlias / /home/abdul/Fetchors/Fetchors/wsgi.py
    #WSGIDaemonProcess django_app python-path=/home/abdul/Fetchors python-home=/home/abdul/Fetchors/venv
    #WSGIProcessGroup django_app
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.orderfetchers.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

**Here's `Https` Configuration:**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.

    ServerName www.orderfetchers.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

    Alias /static /home/abdul/Fetchors/static
      <Directory /home/abdul/Fetchors/static>
        Require all granted
      </Directory>

      Alias /media /home/abdul/Fetchors/media
      <Directory /home/abdul/Fetchors/media>
        Require all granted
      </Directory>

      <Directory /home/abdul/Fetchors/Fetchors>
        <Files wsgi.py>
          Require all granted
        </Files>
      </Directory>
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/abdul/Fetchors/Fetchors/wsgi.py
    WSGIDaemonProcess django_app python-path=/home/abdul/Fetchors python-home=/home/abdul/Fetchors/venv
    WSGIProcessGroup django_app

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.orderfetchers.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.orderfetchers.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: what is the current error you are getting? you just pasted a bunch of configurations but its hard to start looking for issues without knowing what errors are you experiencing.

Comment: Actually, I couldn’t got any error in the browser, when I load the site, it’s just loading.... after a while site can’t reached!

Comment: have you tried using `curl` to access the site. try with `curl --insecure ...` as well in case cert is misconfigured but site is otherwise ok

Comment: curl returns `curl: (7) Failed to connect to www.orderfetchers.com port 443: Operation timed out`

Comment: but with `--insecure` it returns the home page html.

Comment: if `--insecure` returns valid html, this means apache is good but just TLS is misconfigured. personally use nginx so cant help much from here

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr:** Check your firewalls (port 443), and use online tutorials on configs (below).

---

Ok so I had the exact same error that you did - my site had been working fine on port 80 with Apache2 and Django 1.10 on an Ubuntu box, and when I followed a guide for LetsEncrypt, my site would take forever to load before timing out. I am assuming that the question in your post is how to stop your site from just timing out and actually get it to load.

In my case, I was lucky because I was merely an idiot who had forgotten to open port 443 on the AWS Security Group for my Ubuntu box. However, I had some additional config that may help you:

**settings.py**

```
# SSL support
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True

# session expire at browser close
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True

# wsgi scheme
os.environ['wsgi.url_scheme'] = 'https'
```

**wsgi.py**

```
os.environ['HTTPS'] = "on"
```

These configs were found and compiled with the help of these reference sites (which may also help you):

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/05/11/how-to-setup-ssl-certificate-on-nginx-for-django-application.html

https://www.pdxpixel.com/blog/2014/02/04/setting-up-django-site-ssl-apache-mod_wsgi-mod_ssl/

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/security/#ssl-https

Without more understanding of what your system is, it's difficult to help more precisely, but this is what I found useful, so hopefully it helps.